# regex how to find those lines that don't start with a given string?

Tags: regex, perl

what regex can i use using perl flavor, to find all those lines that don't start with the tag .

the text i have is more or less like this:

```
<english> text text text text.
<english> text text text.
text text text
```

i need to verify, that all lines start with  and i want to see all of those that don't start with it.

what i have tried is :

```
^[^<english>].*$

(?!^<english>).*

(?<!<english>).*

.*(?!<english>).*
```

but non of those work.

can somebody please help me, and explain the provided regex? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it as:

`^(?!<english>).*?$` with the `g` and `m` modifier

This matches those lines that **do not** start with `<english>`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/xZ1xF4

Comment: can you please explain me, why is necessary the m modifier?  thanks for the answer.

Comment: @alex, The m modifier is to treat each line individually with the ^ and $

Comment: i see, was easy, but without knowing it, it kind of misterious, now is clear, i read about it in some other pages, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any assertions, just do the test:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^<english>/) {
        print "matches:  $_";
    } else {
        print "no match: $_";
    }
}

__DATA__
<english> text text text text.
<english> text text text.
text text text
```